# auto-refilled nuclear fusion generator

Tags: fusion, perpetual-motion

I read in a science article that in a nuclear fusion reactor, the energy we bring to the reaction is multiplied by a coefficient *q*. This coefficient needs to be at a certain level (around 7 if my memory's good) to allow the reaction to power itself, and higher to produce electricity.

The fuel of this reaction is a solution of Deuterium and Tritium, that we obtain with the help of electricity.

What if one managed to make a fusion generator, that produces enough electricity to create its own fuel (through the corresponding module) ?
This would create a perpetual cycle...

So where is the error in this reasoning ?
I couldn't find it, I don't know much in advanced physics.

Comment: Perhaps if reworded and the claim is cited this would be suitable for skeptics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm currently looking for the sources of my documentation. It's quite hard, I read most of this quite long ago now...

Comment: Why do you believe a perpetual motion machine should be possible?

Comment: I don't. That's why I'm asking. Where is the error in my reasoning ?

Comment: A closed-system perpetual motion machine is impossible - if you keep putting energy into it (ie. more fuel), it's not the same thing.

Comment: In the case I described, the reaction produces anough energy to be self-sustained. (This is how I understood the article I read - And that I'm trying to find)

Comment: @Jean-Marc Zimmer I'm saying you were right - when the planet runs out of fuel, so will the machine, unless, you put more in, ditto with the solar system, ditto the galaxy - not a closed system.

Comment: I finally understood it with S. Mcgrew's answer. And now I feel quite dumb. Really annoying.

Comment: Why was this closed? The question is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the interpretation of "create its own fuel".  A farmer creates his own fuel in a sense.  But to obtain his fuel (food) he is really harnessing energy that is available from his environment (sunlight, which allows his crops to grow).  Tritium and deuterium are not created from scratch.  Deuterium exists naturally ; it is one of the isotopes of hydrogen.  Tritium must be manufactured from other elements, but it takes much less energy to make tritium than the amount of energy produced when deuterium and tritium fuse.  In the case of fusion, the energy already available in the environment is the nuclear potential energy: light elements *want* to fuse to make any element up to the atomic weight of iron; and that fusion yields usable energy.  By analogy: coal and air *want* to burn to produce carbon dioxide; we harness the process to generate electricity..  The chemical potential energy that powers a coal fired electrical generator comes from the sun.  The nuclear potential energy that powers a nuclear fusion reaction comes from the Big Bang that produced the light elements.

Comment: I'm gonna read this a couple more times to understand... -English is not my main language-

Comment: OK, so the process I described is not a perpetual cycle.